# Нужна ли запятая в этом предложении перед "с чего"?

Tags: пунктуация

Он уже хотел начать, но не знал (,) с чего.

Comment: Не нужна.******

Answer (score 2):

Не нужна: запятая перед неполным придаточным предложением не ставится, если оно состоит из одного только союзного слова.

http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/49.htm

(С предлогом у Розенталя тоже есть пример: "в чём" не отделяется запятой.)